# JQ add key to json if condition satisfies

Tags: arrays, json, jq

There are many solutions but sadly none of them worked out for me, so here is my problem
Example

```
{
  "name": "bar some random string",
  "thing": true,
  "new_key": 0
}
{
  "name": "biz again another length words",
  "thing": true,
  "new_key": 0
}
```

So, my problem was if name contains "random" add key value "Contains" : 1 else "contains" : 0

Solution I tried was

```
if .name == "random" then . |= . + {"Contains": 1} else . |= . + {"Contains": 0} end
```

What I need is

```
{
  "name": "bar some random string",
  "thing": true,
  "new_key": 0
  "Contains": 1
}
{
  "name": "biz again another length words",
  "thing": true,
  "new_key": 0
  "Contains": 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it short and sweet:

```
.Contains = (if .name | contains("random")
             then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
if .name  | contains("random") then . |= . + {"Contains": 1} else . |= . + {"Contains": 0} end
```